# Path finding in 2d dimension

Tags: c#, algorithm

I have developed a top down multiplayer browser shooter. Players play against each other. The best players are displayed on the leaderboard. I want to implement bots so that players can play the game even if there no other real players in the room. I am interested retested in navigation aspects of the implementation. Please suggest where to start and how to find an optimal path for my bots through the map.
The map has few obstacles on it. I want my bots to be able to find a path to other players.
Here is the game for reference:
http://thepixelwarrior.com/

Best regards,
Alexander

Comment: Start with Dijkstra algorithm : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest A* Algorithm
It's wide used in game path finding.

[https://www.simplilearn.com/tutorials/artificial-intelligence-tutorial/a-star-algorithm#:~:text=MLExplore%20Program-,What%20is%20an%20A*%20Algorithm%3F,shortest%20path%20to%20be%20taken](https://www.simplilearn.com/tutorials/artificial-intelligence-tutorial/a-star-algorithm#:%7E:text=MLExplore%20Program-,What%20is%20an%20A*%20Algorithm%3F,shortest%20path%20to%20be%20taken).